# lxml node comparison

Tags: python, lxml

Is there a way to check nodes equal with lxml library? For example in php DOMDocument there is `isSameNode`:

```
a->isSameNode(b) //return boolean
```

I need it to do something like this:

```
def find_special_node(special_node, xml):
    #iterating nodes in xml
    if node == special_node:
        return node
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use xpath to find the item, using attributes of "special_node" as required attributes (and values) in find().  I assume that two nodes are determined to be the same if all attributes of the nodes are the same (such as type, value, size, etc.)
Just a guess

My implementation:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
def isSameNode(a,b,tagsame=True):
    for attrib in a.attrib:
        if a.get(attrib) != b.get(attrib):
            print a.get(attrib),b.get(attrib)
            return False
        else:
            return False
    if a.text != b.text:
        return False
    if tagsame==True:
        if a.tag != b.tag:
            return False
    if a.prefix != b.prefix:
        return False
    if a.tail != b.tail:
        return False
    if a.values()!=b.values(): #may be redundant to the attrib matching
        return False
    if a.keys() != b.keys(): #may also be redundant to the attrib matching
        return False
    return True

def find_alike(xml,special_element,tagsame=True):
    tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
    for node in tree.iter():
        if isSameNode(node,special_element,tagsame):
            return node
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to check `NodeA is NodeB` or `NodeA == NodeB`

You may try:

```
for node in X.iter():
    if node == special_node: # maybe "node is special_node" ?
        return node
```

Anyway, since you already have `special_node`, why would you search for it?

Comment: For example i need to check if my `special_node` is in `xml`. But anyway, i need to know if there analogue of php `isSameNode`

Comment: both `node == special_node` and `node is special_node` are not working

Comment: That may be because of the fact that the memory locations are different.  (Just guessing.)  This is what my implementation is doing.>>> i
<Element nodelist2 at 21f6210>
>>> find_alike(s,i)  #s is my xml string.
<Element nodelist2 at 21f6300>